# How to put image across both columns, IEEEtran latex template [Answered]

Tags: graphics, two-column, ieeetran

[image]

I want to put the figure like this on the paper which comprises both columns. How to do that? I would like to know how to do that for tables as well.

Comment: Typically in two-column formats you should use the starred environments `{figure*}` and `{table*}` to have floats spanning both columns.

Comment: Thanks @campa for your answer

Comment: @sam5922 Instead of editing "answer" into your title, it would be better to use the dialog provided to acknowledge that "yes, the suggestion does answer my question".